# Read emails from Outlook subfolder

Tags: vb.net, outlook

How can I read mails from an Outlook subfolder? I can read from Inbox but I have no idea how to read from a folder that I have created in Inbox.

Here my simple code for console application:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim otkApp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
    Dim otkMailItem = "IPM.Note"
    Dim otkNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace = otkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Dim otkInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = otkNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim otkMailItems As Outlook.Items = otkInboxFolder.Items
    Dim otkMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim iCntr As Integer

    MsgBox(otkMailItems.Count)
    For iCntr = 1 To otkMailItems.Count
        If otkMailItems.Item(iCntr).MessageClass = otkMailItem Then
            otkMessage = otkMailItems.Item(iCntr)

            Console.WriteLine(iCntr)
            Console.WriteLine(otkMessage.SenderName)
            Console.WriteLine(otkMessage.Subject)
            Console.WriteLine(otkMessage.ReceivedTime)
            Console.WriteLine(otkMessage.Body)
            Console.WriteLine("______________________________")
        End If
    Next

    otkApp = Nothing
    otkNameSpace = Nothing
    otkMailItems = Nothing
    otkMessage = Nothing
End Sub
```

I think this line should be changed:

```
Dim otkInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = otkNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
```

my folder from that I want to read the mails is:

```
Inbox -> domain.com -> support@domain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the Outlook.NameSpace.Folders("folder_name") property. every time you call this property it will return a MAPIFolder which also have the Folders property so you can use it if you want to access nested folder

for example, let’s say you want to access the folder named "Inbox" which is inside the folder "domain.com" which is inside the folder "support@domain.com" you will be using the following:

```
Dim otkInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = otkNameSpace.Folders("support@domain.com").Folders("domain.com").Folders("Inbox")
```

Comment: Some commentary might help explain this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a subfolder of the Inbox folder, you can use the MAPIFolder.Folders collection to get to the child subfolders.

```
Dim otkInboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = otkNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
Dim SubFolder = otkInboxFolder.Folders.Item*"TheSubfolderName")
Dim otkMailItems As Outlook.Items = SubFolder .Items
```